# DateTime formatting: Why don't ToShortTimeString and "{0:t}" display the same thing?

Tags: c#, datetime

```
var todayAt2PM = new DateTime(
    DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 14, 0, 0);
Debug.Print("{0:t}", todayAt2PM);
Debug.Print("{0}", todayAt2PM.ToString("t"));
Debug.Print("{0}", todayAt2PM.ToShortTimeString());
```

When I run this in C#, I get:

> 14:00
>   2:00 PM
>   2:00 PM

`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` and `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` are both set to "en-US" on my PC.  I haven't done any customizations to my regional settings; when I go to that part of Control Panel, everything indicates 12-hour time, with AM and PM.

So why does "{0:t}" print using 24-hour time?

Comment: `DateTime.Today.AddHours(14)`

Comment: @SLaks: What is this comment supposed to tell us?

Comment: @Daniel: It's a much shorter version of his second line

Comment: @SLaks: Yes, you are right. Next time, please at least add a little hint to your code ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is with `Debug.Print` rather than with the `t` format specifier. If you use `Console.WriteLine` instead of `Debug.Print`, it gives the expected result.

EDIT: just had a look with Reflector... `Debug.Print` always uses the invariant culture, not the current culture, and the time format in that culture is 24-hour

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
public static void Print(string format, params object[] args)
{
    TraceInternal.WriteLine(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, format, args));
}
```